# Interact with TRF7970A NFC chip using Android

Tags: android, nfc

I need to read the contents written in TRF7970A NFC Passive Target through my NFC Android phone. Is it possible somehow? Using API or some JAR file?

If not able to read contents, how can i just detect the chip type through Android code??

Anyone has a solution, please help..

Comment: Did you read the [relevant SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html)?

Comment: Yes,i have earlier worked on NFC project using MiFare Classic NFC chip. My App was able to read and write onto the NFC tag. But, in this case, even the Native Application of Samsung galaxy phone is not able to detect the TRF7970A chip. Do you have some sample code of how to detect it?